# Sample path of a Gaussian Process in $L^2$

Tags: probability, functional-analysis, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, hilbert-spaces

Consider a compact set $X\subset \mathbb R^d$. Let $k:X^2\to\mathbb R$ be a continuous and symmetric positive semi-definite function (that is for all finite subset $\{x_1\dots x_N\}\subset X$, the Gram matrix $(k(x_i,x_j))_{i,j}$ is positive semi-negative). Then there exists a centered Gaussian Process with $k$ as covariance function.

Is the continuity of $k$ enough to ensure that there is a version of the process whose samples are almost surely in $L^2(X,\mu)$ for any finite Borel measure $\mu$ on $X$?

If $k$ is Lipschitz continuous, then the samples are continuous with probability $1$ (see Corollary 2.2 in [https://galton.uchicago.edu/~lalley/Courses/386/GaussianProcesses.pdf](https://galton.uchicago.edu/%7Elalley/Courses/386/GaussianProcesses.pdf)), and so they will be in $L^2(X,\mu)$.

But what if we have just continuity? I would expect it to be enough, probably it can be proven starting from Karhunen-Loève decomposition, but I am not sure if it is indeed the case.